# Imported products show up in backend but not on front end

Tags: import, products, magento-2.1, multiselect, cvs

I was able to import products without issue and they would show up fine on the front end. I was in single user mode. I have one store. I have the column product_websites set to base. Nothing has changed in the import sheet I use but now anything I import will not show up on the front end unless I resaved it on the backend.

I ran a reindex manually and the product prices index did return this error **`(there were more special characters repeated but I left them out):`**

> Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '1622-138-1-55' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO
>   `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`
>   (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?),
>   (?, ?, ?, ?),

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be very grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Normally after once importing data it doesn't work in frontend. We need to re-index.

the message means you are doing another insert with the same combination of columns that are part of the catalog_product_index_eav_idx, which seams to be defined as UNIQUE. If it is so, it doesn't allow to enter same combination (it seems like it consists of two fields) twice.

If you are inserting records, make sure you are picking brand new record id or that the combination of record id and the other column is unique.

Without detailed table structure and your code, we can hardly guess whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use Magento databe repair tool, that tool compare two datbase one fresh database and your database, usualy that solve some problems http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/database-repair-tool.html
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I realized that I had created an accidental category in my spreadsheet by having two commas ,, between a category. I deleted this category and I imagine that this is what caused the issue in future imports.